# Problem with Oracle 10g for writing trigger that will create CSV file with the contents of the data in table

Tags: triggers, oracle10g

How can a trigger be written which is invoked after updating a particular column in the table and creates a [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file with the contents of same table?

I am using [Oracle 10g](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_10g).

Comment: where do you want the csv file being written to?

Comment: Sorry, but I think this is a really bad idea. There are a number of problems you might come across and have to deal with - e.g. (a) if a user performs an update, but then rolls back, the csv file will be created with data that never existed in the table; and (b) in some cases (due to locking issues), if you run an update across many rows in the table, the trigger might be run more than once (Oracle might have to rollback and start again). t.b.c.

Comment: A better approach might be to have a process that detects changes to the table then writes the csv file - i.e. after changes have been committed. Another approach is to use an external table which is updated from the trigger - that way Oracle will handle the file writing/updating as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE [OR REPLACE] TRIGGER trigger_name

{BEFORE/AFTER/INSTEAD OF}triggering_event

[WHEN trigger_condition]

[FOR EACH ROW]

trigger_body;
```

from http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/oracle-10g/oracle-10g-triggers-and-triggering-events.html

Comment: +1 I rarely see people actually refencing the palce from where they paste their answers. Good of you.!

Answer (score 0):

This should do it (of course, modify to fit your table/columns first):

```
create or replace trigger create_csv
after update on table_name for each row
declare
  file_handle text_io.file_type;
  cursor c_table_name is
    select foo, bar, baz
      from table_name
  ;
begin
  file_handle := text_io.fopen('path/to/csv/file');
  for table_row in c_table_name loop
    text_io.put_line(
      file_handle,
      replace(table_row.foo, ',', '\,')||','||
      replace(table_row.bar, ',', '\,')||','||
      replace(table_row.baz, ',', '\,')
    );
  end loop;
  text_io.fclose(file_handle);
end;
```